# Best way to Simplify (or applying other functions to) a SymmetrizedArray

Tags: sparse-arrays, array, symmetrize

I wanted to perform an element-wise `Simplify[]` on a SymmetrizedArray, but I couldn't find an efficient way to do so without converting it to a "Normal" array. To illustrate what I meant, consider the following:

```
array = SparseArray[{{1, 3} -> Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2}]
Map[Simplify, array, {2}]
```

This would still give the output as a SparseArray

[image: SparseArray]

but if I try the same thing with SymmetrizedArray

```
array = SymmetrizedArray[{{1, 3} -> Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2}, {3, 3}, 
  Antisymmetric[{1, 2}]]
Map[Simplify, array, {2}]
```

Then I get a list of lists as the output

```
{{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}}
```

Is there any way I can perform this simplification while keeping the symmetrised property of the array? This is really important for me as the normal form takes up so much unnecessary memory, especially when I want to symmetrise over more indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether it's the optimal or the best way, but you can go through an intermediate "sparse" representation with [`SymmetrizedArrayRules`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SymmetrizedArrayRules.html):

```
mapSymmetrized[f_, arr_] := SymmetrizedArray[Map[f, SymmetrizedArrayRules[arr], {2}], 
  Dimensions[arr], TensorSymmetry[arr]]

mapSymmetrized[Simplify, array]
(* SymmetrizedArray[ ... ] *)
```

Perhaps even better, you may use [`SymmetrizedReplacePart`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SymmetrizedReplacePart.html):

```
mapSymmetrized[f_, arr_] := SymmetrizedReplacePart[arr, Map[f,
  SymmetrizedArrayRules[arr], {2}]]
```